# Flex transition: Stretch (or shrink) to fit content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I have coded a script (with the help of a user here) which allows me to expand a selected div and make the other divs behave accordingly by stretching equally to fit the remaining space (except the first one which width is fixed).

And here is a picture of what I want to achieve:

[image]

For that I use flex and transitions.

It works well, but the jQuery script specifies a "400%" stretch value (which is great for testing).

Now I would like the selected div to expand/shrink to exactly fit the content instead of the "400%" fixed value.

I have no idea how I could do that.

Is it possible ?

I tried to clone the div, fit it to the content, get its value and then use this value to transition BUT this means I have an initial width in percentages but a target value in pixels. That doesn't work.

And if I convert the pixel value in percentages, then the result doesn't exactly fit the content for whatever reason.

In all cases, this seems a bit of a complicated way to achieve what I want anyway.

Isn't there any flex property that could be transitioned in order to fit the content of a selected div?

Here is the code (**edited/simplified since for a better read**) :

```js
var expanded = '';

$(document).on("click", ".div:not(:first-child)", function(e) {

  var thisInd =$(this).index();
  
  if(expanded != thisInd) {
    //fit clicked fluid div to its content and reset the other fluid divs 
    $(this).css("width", "400%");
    $('.div').not(':first').not(this).css("width", "100%");
    expanded = thisInd;
  } else {
    //reset all fluid divs
    $('.div').not(':first').css("width", "100%");
    expanded = '';
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
}

.div:first-child {
  min-width: 36px;
  background: #999;
}

.div:not(:first-child) {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.div:not(:first-child) span {
  background: #ddd;
}

.div:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click on the div you want to fit/reset (except the first div)

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="div"><span>Fixed</span></div>
  <div class="div"><span>Fluid (long long long long long text)</span></div>
  <div class="div"><span>Fluid</span></div>
  <div class="div"><span>Fluid</span></div>

</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zajsLrxp/1/

**EDIT: Here is my working solution with the help of you all (sizes updated on window resize + number of divs and first column's width dynamically calculated):**

```js
var tableWidth;
var expanded    = '';
var fixedDivWidth  = 0;
var flexPercentage = 100/($('.column').length-1);

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Set width of first fixed column
    $('.column:first-child .cell .fit').each(function() {
        var tempFixedDivWidth = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        if( tempFixedDivWidth > fixedDivWidth ){fixedDivWidth = tempFixedDivWidth;}
    });
    $('.column:first-child'  ).css('min-width',fixedDivWidth+'px')
 
    //Reset all fluid columns
    $('.column').not(':first').css('flex','1 1 '+flexPercentage+'%')
})

$(window).resize( function() {

    //Reset all fluid columns
    $('.column').not(':first').css('flex','1 1 '+flexPercentage+'%') 
    expanded   = '';
})

$(document).on("click", ".column:not(:first-child)", function(e) {
 
    var thisInd =$(this).index(); 
 
    // if first click on a fluid column
    if(expanded != thisInd) 
    {
        var fitDivWidth=0;
    
        // Set width of selected fluid column
        $(this).find('.fit').each(function() {
            var c = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
            if( c > fitDivWidth ){fitDivWidth = c;}
        });
        tableWidth = $('.mainTable')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width; 
        $(this).css('flex','0 0 '+ 100/(tableWidth/fitDivWidth) +'%')
  
        // Use remaining space equally for all other fluid column
        $('.column').not(':first').not(this).css('flex','1 1 '+flexPercentage+'%')
  
        expanded = thisInd;
    }

    // if second click on a fluid column
    else
    {
        //Reset all fluid columns
        $('.column').not(':first').css('flex','1 1 '+flexPercentage+'%')

        expanded = '';
    }
  
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.mainTable {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    margin-top : 20px;
}

.cell{
    height: 32px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.cell:first-child{
    background: #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

.column {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    transition: flex 0.4s;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

.column:first-child {
    background: #ccc;
}

.column:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="text">Click on the header div you want to fit/reset (except the first one which is fixed)</span>

<div class="mainTable">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Propriété</span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Artisan 45</span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Waterloo 528</span></div>     
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">     
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Adresse</span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Rue du puit n° 45 (E2)</span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Chaussée de Waterloo n° 528 (E1)</span></div>     
    </div>
  
    <div class="column">     
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Commune</span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Ixelles</span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Watermael-Boitsfort</span></div>     
    </div>
      
    <div class="column">     
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Ville</span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Marche-en-Famenne</span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Bruxelles</span></div>     
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">Surface</span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">120 m<sup>2</sup></span></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="fit">350 m<sup>2</sup></span></div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a fully fledged example at work (styles + padding + more data):

https://jsfiddle.net/zrqLowx0/2/

Thank you all !

Comment: Please be kind enough to add a **final result** to your question showing what you created after all this. I am genuinly interested in what it looks like. Thanks! (...maybe some insight on what it is used for?...)

Comment: Ok, I'll do that as soon as I cleaned my script from all the unnecessary elements (in a few minutes I guess). That said, how do I do that? Do I just edit the original post and add my take on this even though Azametzin answer is perfectly fine? I changes a few things but it's 90% the same (I would be glad to show it though) ..

Comment: Here is the point: I emulate a kind of excel spreadsheet and I want people to be able to click a particular column to fit the content. Normally a table would do but columns are not behaving correctly when it comes to resizing them the way I want (easy to expand one column at a time but it's hard to make the others behave in real time in order to occupy the remaining space the way flex would do for divs. They just expand erratically.I made some research and what I want is impossible with tables). There are other reasons I don't use a table or dataTable but it's outside o the scope of this post.

Comment: Easy enough, just hit 'edit', go to the end of the question and start adding some prozaic ponderings, including a new snippet (all of it). Make sure to 'hide snippet' by default (bottom left checkbox), less intrusive/distracting for 'new readers'. My first thought was that you were going to use it for some fancy 'harmonica'-like widget, icons and all. Spreadsheet huh, I do have some full screen, stretching all over the place up/down/left/right laying around using the same principles  discussed here (if you're interested).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I would love to see your take on spreadsheets bells and whistles.
Mine is supposed to be expandable (now, lol) and columns are interchangeable, sortable, filterable. dataTables are doing 80% of the job, true, but I eventually got away from them because it's rigid and the remaining 20% I needed were conflicting with it. I started it all over again trying not to use any library other than the basic jQuery. And I eventually gave up on tables because they have some fundamental restrictions that don't suit my needs.

Comment: Original post updated with the custom solution!

Comment: Great you went the extra mile posting the final result. Makes answering questions on SO much more rewarding! Cudos...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to solve it using `max-width` and `calc()`.

First, replace `width: 100%` with `flex: 1` for the divs in CSS, so they will grow, which is better in this case.  In addition, use transition for `max-width`.

Now, we have to store some relevant values:

- The amount of divs that will be animated (`divsLength` variable) - 3 in this case.
- The total width used for the fixed div and the borders (`extraSpace` variable) - 39px in this case.

With those 2 variables, we can set a default `max-width` (`defaultMaxWidth` variable) to all the divs, as well as using them later. That is why they are being stored globally.

The `defaultMaxWidth` is `calc((100% - extraSpace)/divsLength)`.

**Now, let's enter the click function:**

To expand the div, the width of the target text will be stored in a variable called `textWidth` and it will be applied to the div as `max-width.` It uses `.getBoundingClientRect().width` (since it return the floating-point value).

For the remaining divs, it is created a `calc()` for `max-width` that will be applied to them.
It is: `calc(100% - textWidth - extraScape)/(divsLength - 1)`.
The calculated result is the width that each remaining div should be.

When clicking on the expanded div, that is, to return to normal, the default `max-width` is applied again to all `.div` elements.

```js
var expanded = false,
    divs = $(".div:not(:first-child)"),
    divsLength = divs.length,
    extraSpace = 39, //fixed width + border-right widths 
    defaultMaxWidth = "calc((100% - " + extraSpace + "px)/" + divsLength + ")";

    divs.css("max-width", defaultMaxWidth);

$(document).on("click", ".div:not(:first-child)", function (e) {
  var thisInd = $(this).index();

  if (expanded !== thisInd) {
    
    var textWidth = $(this).find('span')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;  
    var restWidth = "calc((100% - " + textWidth + "px - " + extraSpace + "px)/" + (divsLength - 1) + ")";
    
    //fit clicked fluid div to its content and reset the other fluid divs 
    $(this).css({ "max-width": textWidth });
    $('.div').not(':first').not(this).css({ "max-width": restWidth });
    expanded = thisInd;
  } else {
    //reset all fluid divs
    $('.div').not(':first').css("max-width", defaultMaxWidth);
    expanded = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
}

.div:first-child {
  min-width: 36px;
  background: #999;
}

.div:not(:first-child) {
  flex: 1;
  transition: max-width 1s;
}

.div:not(:first-child) span {
  background: #ddd;
}

.div:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click on the div you want to fit/reset (except the first div)

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="div"><span>Fixed</span></div>
  <div class="div"><span>Fluid (long long long long text)</span></div>
  <div class="div"><span>Fluid</span></div>
  <div class="div"><span>Fluid</span></div>

</div>
```

This approach behaves dynamically and should work on any resolution.
The only value you need to hard code is the `extraSpace` variable.

Comment: Couldn't help but trying and the outcome is definitely unpredictable. Depending on the window size, I get various results. Sometimes there is no transition at all (it just switches from one size to another), sometimes, the transition is quick, sometimes super slow. It seems that the 1000% approximation isn't transparent and its effect is more or less tangible depending on the window size.
It seems I get the 2 side effects you predicted.
Note that because of the different sizes of the div contents as well as the overall window, sometimes the div should expand and sometimes it should shrink..

Comment: The idea is elegant but as such it is just not reliable...
I tried to workaround this by getting the "textWidth" size and transform it in percentage and apply that percentage to the css width attribute instead of 1000%. That works actually but it's almost a fit, not an exact fit. The marge of error depends on how large the windows is and how large the content is. I don't know why there is a marge of error since the percentage I get is very precise (floating value).

Comment: Yes, this is a problem that requires a precise calculation and a greater understanding of the flexbox shrink effect. I don't have a "perfect" solution yet but I would like to try again in the future, so I bookmarked your question for another time to try to figure out how to do it right. It is a good challenge.

Comment: Just FYI, I edited the code since to make it simpler to read and test. I added the spans which are a good addition. I haven't added the max-width transitions however as so far, they didn't work great.

Comment: Nice! Take your time as I'm out for a couple of hours anyway ;-)

Comment: Oooh, I just saw your edited comment (was expecting an update comment). The use of getBoundingClientRect() is very clever and it didn't occur to me (same for taking the 39 px fixed width into account). I will test a bit more to see if it works for any windows size and any number of Fluid divs. I'll get back to you. Thank you very much!
PS: your solution works with jQuery 3.3.1 but NOT with 3.4.1, for whatever reason.

Comment: I forgot to comment before. How strange, I tested it with jQuery 3.4.1 and it worked well. I changed the answer a bit in JavaScript and put jQuery version 3.4.1. :). Also, the other guy who answered solved it in a much simpler way. He just forgot to remove the class from what is already expanded, but it works very well. I tried to make it it starting from your code and it got more complex, but it was fun to solve.

Comment: I get issues with various window sizes and div amounts.
The other script here below works in order to fit the content but fails at sizing the other divs correctly. To fix this, I have to come back to your script. And once I play with both your scripts, it weirdly seems that a mix of both might work.  I'm testing and once done i'l get back to you.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce what you mean. Could you give me a snippet as an example of an HTML structure that is failing?

Comment: I consider your script to be a valid solution to my question.
Other elements in my code conflicts with your script but your script as such is just fine.
I ended up mixing both your script and the use of flex transition instead of max-width and it works like a charm now.
It's the best of both worlds and the code is lighter (no need for making up for the first fixed div by adding it to the calculation).
That said, your script works perfectly fine so no need for any update here.
Thank you very much for your help and solution!

Comment: Great! Thank you for the opportunity to develop this solution. It was a lot of fun days in this saga. :)

Comment: Thank you again ! I'll edit the original post with the custom solution and a more sophisticated html, if you are interested in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to deal with the width or calc functions. Flexbox would have a solution.

To make all divs equal (not first one) we use `flex: 1 1 auto`.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div"><span>Fixed</span></div>
  <div class="div"><span>Fluid (long long long long text)</span></div>
  <div class="div"><span>Fluid</span></div>
  <div class="div"><span>Fluid</span></div>
</div>
```

Define flex rules for your normal div and selected div. `transition: flex 1s;` is your friend. For selected one we don't need flex grow so we use `flex: 0 0 auto`;

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  transition: flex 1s;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.div.selected{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.div:first-child {
  min-width: 50px;
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
}

.div:not(:first-child) {
  text-align: center;
}

.div:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}

div:not(:first-child) span {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

Add selected class each time when the user clicks a div. You can also use toggle for the second click so you can save selected items in a map and you can show multiple selected items (not with this code example of course).

```
$(document).on("click", ".div:not(:first-child)", function(e) {
  const expanded = $('.selected');
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  if (expanded) {
    expanded.removeClass("selected");
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f3ao8xcj/

Comment: Thank you. I have to study your case because it does the opposite of what I want and I'm not sure how to reverse that yet (maybe it's trivial).
I want, by default, all fluid divs to be equally large. it's only when I click on one that this one fits its content (and the other fluid divs share equally the remaining space).
And if I click a second time on the same div, all Fluid divs reset, sharing equally the space again with no concern about their content whatsoever.
So, if I'm not mistaken, it's the exact opposite of what you did. Not sure yet how to reverse that.

Comment: However, if this can be reversed, I really like how elegant and how simple your solution is as there is no need for messing with the css width attribute. Flex seems to just handle this internally. That said, I have a hunch it'll be more difficult to achieve the opposite way. Wait and see. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri it fairly simple again. Please see the updated version.

Comment: I love the elegance of your script but your solutions only consider parts of my request. My request is not only about fitting the content, it's also about sharing the remaining space equally before, during and after clicking the fluid divs. Your script doesn’t address that very well, if not at all. And that's what makes the whole thing a brain burner. I added a picture in the original post to make my needs very clear. The other script above starts exactly where yours fails to deliver. It weirdly seems that a mix of both your scripts might work. I'm testing and once done i'l get back to you.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri What you are missing here is, nobody needs to provide a perfect solution on for your case. `Flex transition: Stretch (or shrink) to fit content` is your question title and this answer is the simple example of how to do it. It is your responsibility to find the solution for your case.

Comment: What I think you are missing is that your solution ends when the other solution starts. Which means that when yours is working without the other aspects of the question, it's exactly when we get the initial part of the problem. That's a first.
The second point is that it is a bounty right now. And it is because I'm looking for a solution that works with my requirements that I invest some reputation. Something that works in theory outside of any constraint is not a solution, it's a concept.
If I need to get a fitted text surrounded by equally large divs, half a solution isn't a solution.

Answer (score 2):

After a few trial versions, this seems to be my shortest and most straighforward solution.

All that essentially needs to be done is have Flexbox stretch the `<div>` elements to their limits by default, but when `<span>` clicked, constraint the stretch of the `<div>` to `<span>` width ...

**pseudo code:**

`when <span> clicked and already toggled then <div> max-width = 100%, reset <span> toggle state`

`otherwise <div> max-width = <span> width, set <span> toggle state`

I have split the CSS into a 'relevant mechanism' and 'eye-candy only' section for easy reading (and code recyling).

The code is heavily commented, so not much text here...

**Quirk** Somehow there is an extra delay in the `transition` when switching the `div` from `max-width: 100%` to `max-width = span width`. I've checked this behaviour in Chrome, Edge, IE11 and Firefox (all W10) and all seem to have this quirk. Either some browser internal recalc going on, or maybe the `transition` time is used twice ('feels like'). Vice Versa, oddly enough, there is no extra delay.

However, with a short transition time (e.g. 150ms, as I am using now) this extra delay is not/hardly noticable. (Nice one for another SO question...)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.wrapper>:not(.caption) span', function (e) {
// Save the current 'toggle' status
var elemToggled = e.target.getAttribute('toggled');

   // Set parent max-width to maximum space or constraint to current child width
    e.target.parentElement.style.maxWidth = 
        (elemToggled=="true") ? '100%' : parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(e.target).width) + 'px';
    
    // (Re)set child toggle state 
    e.target.setAttribute('toggled', (elemToggled=="true") ? false : true);    
});
```

```css
/*********************/
/* Wrapper mechanism */
/*********************/
.wrapper { /* main flexible parent container */
    display  : flex;        /* [MANDATORY] Flexbox Layout container, can't FBL without */
    flex-wrap: nowrap;      /* [MANDATORY] default FBL, but important. wrap to next line messes things up */
    flex-grow: 1;           /* [OPTIONAL] Either: if '.wrapper' is a FBL child itself, allow it to grow */
    width    : 100%;        /* [OPTIONAL] or    : full parent width */
                            /* (Maybe a fixed value, otherwise redundant here as 'flex-grow' = 1) */
}
/* generic rule */
.wrapper>* { /* flexed child containers, being flexible parent containers themselves */
    flex-grow : 1;          /* [MANDATORY] important for this mechanism to work */
    overflow: hidden;       /* [MANDATORY] important, otherwise output looks messy */

    display: flex;          /* [MANDATORY] for FBL stretching */
    justify-content: center;/* [MANDATORY] as per SOQ */

    max-width : 100%;       /* [OPTIONAL/MANDATORY], actually needed to trigger 'transition' */
}
/* exception to the rule */
.wrapper>.fixed { /* fixed child container */
    flex-grow: 0;           /* [MANDATORY] as per SOQ, don't allow grow */
}

/******************/
/* Eye-candy only */
/******************/
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper>:not(.fixed) {
    transition: max-width 150ms ease-in-out; 
}
.wrapper>:not(:last-child){
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
/* generic rule */
.wrapper>*>span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
/* exception to the rule */
.wrapper>.fixed>span {
    background-color: #999;
}

/* debug helper: show all elements with outlines (put in <body>) */
[debug="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed purple }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fixed"><span>Fixed</span></div>
    <div><span>Fluid (long long long long long text)</span></div>
    <div><span>Fluid</span></div>
    <div><span>Fluid</span></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

New version that resets all other `<div>`. I truly hate the jumpiness, but that is due to Flexbox stretching and the `transition` value. Without `transition` no jumps visible. You need to try out what works for you.

I only added `document.querySelectorAll()` to the javascript code.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.wrapper>:not(.caption) span', function (e) {
var elemToggled = e.target.getAttribute('toggled');                    // Toggle status
var elemWidth   = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(e.target).width); // Current element width

    // reset ALL toggles but 'this'...
    document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper>:not(.caption) span')
        .forEach( function (elem,idx) {
                      if (elem != this){
                         elem.parentElement.style.maxWidth = '100%';
                         elem.setAttribute('toggled',false);
                      };
                  });

    // Set parent max-width to maximum space or constraint to current child width
    e.target.parentElement.style.maxWidth = 
        (elemToggled=="true") ? '100%' : parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(e.target).width) + 'px';

    // (Re)set child toggle state 
    e.target.setAttribute('toggled', (elemToggled=="true") ? false : true);    
});
```

```css
/*********************/
/* Wrapper mechanism */
/*********************/
.wrapper { /* main flexible parent container */
    display  : flex;        /* [MANDATORY] Flexbox Layout container, can't FBL without */
    flex-wrap: nowrap;      /* [MANDATORY] default FBL, but important. wrap to next line messes things up */
    flex-grow: 1;           /* [OPTIONAL] Either: if '.wrapper' is a FBL child itself, allow it to grow */
    width    : 100%;        /* [OPTIONAL] or    : full parent width */
                            /* (Maybe a fixed value, otherwise redundant here as 'flex-grow' = 1) */
}
/* generic rule */
.wrapper>* { /* flexed child containers, being flexible parent containers themselves */
    flex-grow : 1;          /* [MANDATORY] important for this mechanism to work */
    overflow: hidden;       /* [MANDATORY] important, otherwise output looks messy */

    display: flex;          /* [MANDATORY] for FBL stretching */
    justify-content: center;/* [MANDATORY] as per SOQ */

    max-width : 100%;       /* [OPTIONAL/MANDATORY], actually needed to trigger 'transition' */
}
/* exception to the rule */
.wrapper>.fixed { /* fixed child container */
    flex-grow: 0;           /* [MANDATORY] as per SOQ, don't allow grow */
}

/******************/
/* Eye-candy only */
/******************/
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper>:not(.fixed) {
    transition: max-width 150ms ease-in-out; 
}
.wrapper>:not(:last-child){
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
/* generic rule */
.wrapper>*>span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
/* exception to the rule */
.wrapper>.fixed>span {
    background-color: #999;
}
/* show all elements with outlines (put in <body>) */
[debug="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed purple }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fixed"><span>Fixed</span></div>
    <div><span>Fluid (long long long long long text)</span></div>
    <div><span>Fluid</span></div>
    <div><span>Fluid</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your proposal. It doesn't fit my needs (but it's a very good starting point) as when we click on a fluid div, it fits alright but the two other divs don't expand equally to occupy the remaining space. Which is 50% of the issue. And yes, there is this quirkiness too.
The script of Azametzin does the job 100% with no quirkiness..
I ended up mixing both his script and the use of flex transition instead of max-width and it works like a charm.
Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Seconding  @Azametzin s' remark: It was a lot of fun days in this saga. :). Maybe next time start with the image?

Comment: Ok. I thought the explanation were enough but obviously, I was wrong. The image is there since yesterday though. But I get your point. I'll edit my original message to show my custom script in a matter of minutes. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one row, there is a simpler solution based on this code : https://jsfiddle.net/jpeter06/a5cu52oy/
with the css flex modified for columns instead of rows :

```
.container {
    flex-grow: 10;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}
.item { min-width:30px;
        flex-basis:30px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        transition: flex-basis 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.expanded {
   flex-basis: 20em;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; overflow: hidden;  
}
```

html code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="background: red">a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/></div>
    <div class="item" style="background: green">b<br/>b<br/>b<br/>b</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: blue">c<br/>c<br/>c<br/>c</div>
</div>
```

JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $(".item").not(this).each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("expanded");    
    });
  });
});
```